# Symfony 2 override existing service definition in config?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

In

vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security.xml

```
    <service id="security.access.role_hierarchy_voter" class="%security.access.role_hierarchy_voter.class%" public="false">
        <argument type="service" id="security.role_hierarchy" />
        <tag name="security.voter" priority="245" />
    </service>
```

is defined. The service class, `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\RoleHierarchyVoter` 
 has a second parameter `$prefix = 'ROLE_'` as default value.

In above service definition, second argument is not passed so it will take default value `ROLE_`

In my application, I have legacy roles, e.g login. which do not have `ROLE_` prefix.

I want to override above service definition and pass second argument empty.

```
         <service id="security.access.role_hierarchy_voter" class="%security.access.role_hierarchy_voter.class%" public="false">
            <argument type="service" id="security.role_hierarchy" />
            <argument></argument>
            <tag name="security.voter" priority="245" />
        </service>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new class which extends `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\RoleHierarchyVoter`.

In the class you created, the prefix is under your control, what you have to do is just change the constructor method.

*Code:*

```
public function __construct(RoleHierarchyInterface $roleHierarchy)
{
    parent::__construct($roleHierarchy, 'THE_PREFIX_YOU_WANT_TO_SET');
}
```

Then set the parameter `security.access.role_hierarchy_voter.class` to the class you created.

*Edit:*

Set the prefix with empty string could cause warning, overwrite `RoleVoter`'s `supportAttribute` is another solution.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but there is another problem, As I do not want prefix, I am passing empty string, and in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/RoleVoter.php,  supportsAttribute()  0 === strpos($attribute, $this->prefix); gives warning as $this->prefix is empty

Comment: I think, its better to override RoleVoter and return always true from supportAttribute ?

Comment: @user1191081 Yep, just try it out :)

Comment: yeah it worked. Thanks. would you like to modify your answer ?

Comment: Actully dont need to override RoleHierarchyVote, added complete working solution